# Calling a python web server within a script

Tags: python, web-services, monitoring, status, cherrypy

I would like to have a web server displaying the status of 2 of my python scripts.
These scripts listen for incoming data on a specific port.  What I would like to do is have it so that when the script is running the web server will return a HTTP200 and when the script is not running a 500.  I have had a look at cherrypy and other such python web servers but I could not get them to run first and then while the web server is running continue with the rest of my code.  I would like it so that if the script crashes so does the web server.  Or a way for the web server to display say a blank webpage with just a 1 in the HTML if the script is running or a 0 if it is not.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I was just answering a question moderately similar to this one the idea would be to run script A and have it break off 2 threads running the scripts that you intend and then just have a web page do a:

```
import threading, cherrypy
from cherrypy import expose

class thread1(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        #code for script 1 goes here

class thread2(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        #code for script 2 goes here

t1 = thread1()
t2 = thread2()

t1.start()
t2.start()

@expose
def check(self):
    if t1.isAlive() and t2.isAlive():
        return "1"
    return "0"
```

I would advise you to put either nginx or apache infront of this with them being a reverse proxy.

Now there is 2 ways that this will show you that one of them stopped. Either it will show you a 1 that both are running fine. A zero if one or both stopped but managed to keep the rest of the script running. Or nginx/apache will give you a 500 error saying that the backend server (ie:cherrypy) crashed which means that the entire script stopped working.

Comment: Ah that is clever. I like the solution, very elegant, thank you. Also why the reverse proxy? I was just going to stick it on some obscure port.

Comment: Well if you don't have a reverse proxy then you will not receive a 500 error the request will just time out though that will be another way to check if it is running or not... Its just a suggestion if you were going to be doing it for a production run of something...

Comment: Oh ok.  I can set up the reverse proxy relatively easily.  So that should not be a problem.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.6.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.6.egg/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File

Comment: "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.6.egg/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 386, in __call__
    raise self
NotFound: (404, "The path '/' was not found.")

Comment: You seem to have an error in your script where you are attempting to call something from a path at location / and the file is not there.

Comment: The problem I am having is that if my script runs into an exception specifically mysql server has gone away (2006) The threading will still report it as alive.  Any way I can get round this?

Comment: Well if I am understanding you correctly then you will want it to kill the thread on this error. If that is true then you will have to use `raise SystemExit` like so:
    `try:
        #code here
    except Exception:
        raise SystemExit`

Comment: there should be spacing in that but comments don't have code bloacks the same way that answers/questions do...

Answer (score 2):

I would break it apart further:

- script A, on port a
- script B, on port b
- web script C which checks on A and B (by making simple requests to them)
   and returns the results in a machine-friendly format, ie JSON or XML
- web page D which calls C and formats the results for people, ie an HTML table

There are existing programs which do this - Nagios springs to mind.

Comment: So far I have Script A on a and Script B on b, I would like to try and avoid Script C as it adds another point of failure.